# Can I fly for commercial jobs with just my temporary certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations

I just received my temporary certificate and when I called the airman registry to ask how long it would be before I received my permanent copy, they basically told me it was going to take awhile. So my question is, what can I do with the temporary? Are commercial jobs allowed? Can I apply at private companies to fly for them?

Comment: What certificate are we talking about here?

Comment: If you have a temporary commercial cert and someone will hire you, yes, you can. What makes you think that you can't?  Assuming USA/FAA.

Comment: A temporary certificate has all the privileges as the permanent one.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary certificate is valid for everything that a permanent one is valid for; it's just, well, temporary.

[14 CFR 61.3](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_13):

> No person may serve as a required pilot flight crewmember of a civil
>   aircraft of the United States, unless that person:
>
> (1) Has in the person's physical possession or readily accessible in
>   the aircraft when exercising the privileges of that pilot certificate
>   or authorization—
>
> [...]
>
> (iii) A temporary certificate issued under §61.17;

[61.17](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&r=PART&n=14y2.0.1.1.2#se14.2.61_117):

> A temporary pilot, flight instructor, or ground instructor certificate
>   or rating is issued for up to 120 days, at which time a permanent
>   certificate will be issued to a person whom the Administrator finds
>   qualified under this part.

(See [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1573/62) for what happens when the 120 days are up.)

As far as the FAA is concerned, your temporary certificate is no different from a permanent one. I suppose it's possible that an employer might decline to hire you until you get a permanent certificate but I think that's highly unlikely within the US (employers abroad [might be a different story](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35381/62)). I've seen people pass a CFI checkride and start instructing within a few days, for example.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary certificate has the same privileges as the permanent certificate. A temporary certificate expires after 120 days.

If you temporary certificate is about to expire, you can have a new one issued on the spot at an FAA FSDO, with an appointment.  If the FSDO is not convenient, there is a way to request an extension online.

Temporary certificates are commonplace, as any pilot adding a rating will receive a temporary certificate.

Most permanent certificates have no expiration date, but common exceptions are CFI and Remote Pilot certificates.